# Whats general convention when defining camera/objects z position

Tags: java, opengl

I'm making a switch to generate matrices myself in `java`, to pass into my `opengl` shaders.

I've created a method to generate the perspective matrix which works fine. But currently I have my objects being drawn at `z` position `0.0f`. Which means when the app runs, I can only see 1 of my custom objects (square) really close up.

Should I be setting my camera `z` position to `0.0f` (which is happening currently) .. or all my objects `z` position to `0.0f`?

```
createPerspectiveProjection(60.0f, width / height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

/**
 * @param fov
 * @param aspect
 * @param zNear
 * @param zFar
 * @return projectionMatrix
 */
private Matrix4f createPerspectiveProjection(float fov, float aspect, float zNear, float zFar){

    Matrix4f mat = new Matrix4f();

    float yScale = (float) (1 / (Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fov / 2))));
    float xScale = yScale / aspect;
    float frustrumLength = zFar - zNear;

    mat.m00 = xScale;
    mat.m11 = yScale;
    mat.m22 = -((zFar + zNear) / frustrumLength);
    mat.m23 = -1;
    mat.m32  = -((2 * zFar * zNear) / frustrumLength);
    mat.m33 = 0;

    return mat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard projection matrix you are using corresponds to a camera placed at the origin, and looking down the negative z-axis. The near and far values determine the range of *negative* z-values that are within the view frustum. With the values in the example, this means that z-values between -0.1f and -100.0f are visible. That's as long as they're within the pyramid defined by the field of view angle, of course.

How you place your camera and objects in world space is completely up to you. If you emulate a traditional OpenGL rendering pipeline, you'll have a model-view matrix that transforms your objects to place them in the view frustum described above. This means that visible objects should have a negative z-value after the model-view transformation is applied.

The absolutely simplest way of achieving this is to use the identity transformation (i.e. no transformation at all) for the model-view transformation, and place your objects around the negative z-axis.

However, it's often convenient to have your objects placed somewhere around the origin. One simple way of allowing this to work is to place the camera on the positive z-axis, and point it at the origin. The model-view matrix then becomes particularly simple. It's only a translation in the negative z-direction, to shift the camera from its position on the positive z-axis to the origin, matching how the projection matrix was set up.

For example, with your near/far values of 0.1/100.0, you could place the camera at (0.0, 0.0, 50.0) in world space. The view transformation is then a translation by (0.0, 0.0, -50.0). The z-range from 49.9 to -50.0 in world space is then the visible range, allowing you to place your objects around the origin.